# Получить ссылку из строки. PHP

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка:

```
    <![CDATA[
[视频/Video]ПОДПИШИСЬ➡️ @_prikoly.video_Ставь❤️#вайнвидео #вайны#смешныевайны #юморной #прикол #стендап #новостиюмор#юморtv #телевидение #тнтздесь #камедивумен #смешной #юморfm #нурлансабуров #скетчи #стендаптнт #шутки #камедиклаб #krutos_vidos #комменты #шуткиза300 #девушкадня #камедиклаб #смешноевидео #шуткиради #смеха #взрослый #девушкам #угарныевидео #смехпродлеваетжизньподнимаетнастроениеиделаетнескучнымдень<br><img referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src="https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/d8bb432de6af1dd5536c54702739b668/5C5EB257/t51.2885-15/e15/50504165_2059371954181189_1445399206825334136_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com"><br><video width="100%" controls="controls"> <source src="https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e7a90c6e32342cb367519c322e317075/5C5E2B02/t50.2886-16/52119479_1593895377379694_6408319200951214363_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com" type="video/mp4"> Your RSS reader does not support video playback. </video>
]]>
```

Как используя PHP найти в ней `<source>` и вывести **со всеми атрибутами и их содержимым** его на страницу?

Comment: вы не знаете, как в строке подстроку найти?

Answer (score 1):

```php
<?php

preg_match('/<source ?.*?>/', $subject, $matches);

$found = $matches[0];

echo $found;
```

Результат:

```
<source src="https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e7a90c6e32342cb367519c322e317075/5C5E2B02/t50.2886-16/52119479_1593895377379694_6408319200951214363_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com" type="video/mp4">
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться библиотекой **PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser**

Пример:

```
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$html = str_get_html(' <[CDATA[
[&#35270;&#39057;/Video]ПОДПИШИСЬ&#10145; @_prikoly.video_Ставь&#10084;#вайнвидео #вайны#смешныевайны #юморной #прикол #стендап #новостиюмор#юморtv #телевидение #тнтздесь #камедивумен #смешной #юморfm #нурлансабуров #скетчи #стендаптнт #шутки #камедиклаб #krutos_vidos #комменты #шуткиза300 #девушкадня #камедиклаб #смешноевидео #шуткиради #смеха #взрослый #девушкам #угарныевидео #смехпродлеваетжизньподнимаетнастроениеиделаетнескучнымдень<br><img referrerpolicy="no-referrer" src="https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/d8bb432de6af1dd5536c54702739b668/5C5EB257/t51.2885-15/e15/50504165_2059371954181189_1445399206825334136_n.jpg?_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com"><br><video width="100%" controls="controls"> <source src="https://scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com/vp/e7a90c6e32342cb367519c322e317075/5C5E2B02/t50.2886-16/52119479_1593895377379694_6408319200951214363_n.mp4?_nc_ht=scontent-lga3-1.cdninstagram.com" type="video/mp4"> Your RSS reader does not support video playback. </video>
]]>');
$t = $html->find("source", 0)->type;
echo $t;
```

Результат:

```
video/mp4
```

По аналогии можно другие атрибуты вывести.